# Posting from Nodejs express app to MySQL database returns 404

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying post to MySQL database but getting a 404 error. I have gone through numerous posts here but all the accepted answers didn't work for me. I just can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

When I use a GET request, this code works well:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT shop_name_en, shop_id FROM mst_shop";
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send({ results });
  });
});
```

However, when I try to use POST, it returns a 404 error in console.

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "UPDATE mst_shop SET review_count = 5 WHERE shop_id = 1";
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
    res.send(results);
  })
});
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I tested the MySQL code and it works well when I do it through myphpadmin. I am relatively new to this so I feel like I'm missing something very obvious. Here is my code in context:

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql = require("mysql");
var router = express.Router();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'booo',
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("MySQL database is connected. Noicey!")
});

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "UPDATE mst_shop SET review_count = 5 WHERE shop_id = 1";
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
    res.send(results);
  })
});

module.exports = router;
```

As I mentioned earlier, a get request works well, but not the post.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I have understood what was the problem after lots of trial and error. Seems that I had to use the same `.get` method instead of `.post` method, so the correct way for my code to work was simply changing post to get like so:

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  let sql = "UPDATE mst_shop SET review_count = 5 WHERE shop_id = 1";
  let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
    res.send(results);
  })
});
```